# Grid and Switch Tag unexpected results

Tags: templates, grid, switch

I'm building out a photo gallery using the grid field type and everything works fine with this code:

```
{gallery}
  <li class="{gallery:switch='one|two|three'}">
    <a href="{gallery:photo}"><img src="{gallery:photo:square}" alt="{gallery:caption}" /></a>

    {if gallery:caption}<h5>{gallery:caption}</h5>{/if}
  </li>
{/gallery}
```

However the switch tag is outputting the classes in the wrong order which is why I changed them to numbers, really they should be clear||last. The unexpeced output is here:

```
<ul id="gallery">
  <li class="two">
    <a href="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/test16.jpg"><img src="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/_square/test16.jpg" alt=""></a>

              </li>

  <li class="three">
    <a href="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/test15.jpg"><img src="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/_square/test15.jpg" alt="Mmm Caffeine!"></a>

    <h5>Mmm Caffeine!</h5>          </li>

  <li class="one">
    <a href="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/test12.jpg"><img src="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/_square/test12.jpg" alt="Marshmallows!"></a>

    <h5>Marshmallows!</h5>          </li>

  <li class="two">
    <a href="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/test5.jpg"><img src="http://domain.com/uploads/gallery/_square/test5.jpg" alt="Be Careful"></a>

    <h5>Be Careful</h5>          </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that the classes get output 
two
three
one
two

**not**

one
two 
three

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug, Sean, sorry you got bitten by it. I've reported it and posted a fix here:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19871

Comment: Hi Kevin,

For me the line was 294, not 315 as in the bug report. But regardless bug fixed.